# How to Update the Entity Efficeintly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have model class:

```
@Entity 
public class Customer {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String phone;
    //...
}
```

Now there is an update operation in which I want to update the existing data. My code:

```
public void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Customer existingCustomer = customerRepository.findById(customer.getId())
                                                  .orElse(null);

    /* Now here I want to update only fields which are not null            
       if(customer.getInfo() != null)
       existingCustomer.setInfo(customer.getInfo()); 
    */
    customerRepository.save(existingCustomer);
}
```

How to do this in an effective way as I can't check for each field and set it in my object.

Comment: What if the user wants to update the value explicitly to null ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to combine [JsonNullable](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/jackson-databind-nullable) and [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) features as described in this very detailed [article](https://kdrozd.pl/how-to-perform-a-partial-update-patch-with-explicit-null/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your fields are public as a shortcut for making the question straightforward.

I suggest you to create a special method in your entity that accepts a second entity and iterates over their fields.

e.g.

```java
    class Customer {
        // one hundred fields here
        public void updateOnlyNonNulls(Customer customer){
            for (Field declaredField : Customer.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
                try {
                    Object o = declaredField.get(customer);
                    if(o!=null)
                        declaredField.set(this, o);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new AssertionError("Should not happen");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Do not be [reluctant to add rich behavior to your entities](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).